# Adobe Air native installer Linux - Dependency is not satisfiable

Tags: linux, air, native, deb

I created native installers for my air application successfully under MacOS and Windows.
With Ubuntu 10 I am able to create a .deb package, but when I launch it opens the Ubuntu software center showing error:

Dependency is not satisfiable: adobeair (>= 2.5.0.0)

I thought native installer should be able to download the proper adobe air version if available (2.5.1 seems available as deb package). If I install air for linux 2.5.1 from adobe website my application launches fine.

Did anyone experience the same issue?

Thanks in advance for any help
Paolo

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, many years late "Adobe AIR for Linux is no longer supported." following what adobe page says. Using the "AIR archive" is possible to get unsupported versions, the 2.6.0 version is the most recent available. If you need to install a program that require a newer version of it, you might go to Virtual box with a Windows guest.

For version 2.6.0 the recommend steps for Ubuntu 16.10 are:

for 32bit machine

```
wget -O adobe-air_i386.deb http://drive.noobslab.com/data/apps/AdobeAir/adobeair_2.6.0.2_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i adobe-air_i386.deb
sudo apt-get install -f && rm adobe-air_i386.deb
```

for 64bit machine

```
wget -O adobe-air_amd64.deb http://drive.noobslab.com/data/apps/AdobeAir/adobeair_2.6.0.2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i adobe-air_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f && rm adobe-air_amd64.deb
```

The recommend steps for Ubuntu 16.04/14.04/12.04/Linux Mint 18/17/13 (both extracted from [here](http://www.noobslab.com/2015/05/adobeair-is-now-available-for-ubuntu.html)):

```
wget -O adobe-air.sh http://drive.noobslab.com/data/apps/AdobeAir/adobe-air.sh
chmod +x adobe-air.sh;sudo ./adobe-air.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install itdpkg -i --force-architecture adobeair.deb

Answer (score 0):

What version of the adobeair package is available from the Ubuntu repositories?

A .deb is just an archive and the dependencies have to be available from the repositories the system is configured to use. It can't resolve the dependency by downloading it from some specific location you know of but the system is not configured to use.

If the needed version of the package is not available from the Ubuntu repositories then your only options are to reconfigure the system to use an additional repository that does have the needed dependency before you try to install your package, or download and manually install the dependency before you try to to install your package.